# newcommand that does not expand at all

Tags: macros, expansion

How do I define a command that exactly inserts its contents back into the source file without any reinterpretation, expansion, etcetera?

In other words, I want there never to be a difference between using `\exactly{ugly stuff}` and `ugly stuff` no matter what I stick into `ugly stuff`.

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\exactly}[1]{#1}


\begin{document}



\exactly{ugly stuff}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As TeX is a macro language, `\newcommand` does exactly what you describe. Perhaps you want to see the tokens inserts using say `\verb|content|`?

Comment: Thank you.  I'm confused. I'm doing something with lualatex in which `ugly stuff` contains an environment whose contents are passed verbatim to lua.  If I use `\exactly{ugly stuff}` lua complains for reasons I have to track down, whereas with `ugly stuff` directly in the code, it compiles fine.  Thanks also for your great work on latex3, etcetera.

Comment: Perhaps you should instead ask your real question with a real lua example, as the question is not really answerable in this form.

Comment: but mention of verbatim gives me a hint, I'll attempt a (negative) answer.

Comment: ok, thanks,will try to do that.  This will be painful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (first level) expansion of a macro, whether defined by `\def` or (indirectly) by `\newcommand` is exactly the tokens in its replacement text. So in the normal course of events the behaviour is exactly as you ask.

However if you use

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\exactly}[1]{#1}


\begin{document}



\exactly{ugly \verb|{| stuff}

\end{document}
```

Then it does *not* work like

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\exactly}[1]{#1}


\begin{document}



ugly \verb|{| stuff

\end{document}
```

and this is not really fixable. The argument of `\exactly` is scanned matching braces
and tokenizing input characters before the macro `\exactly` is executed to re-insert that argument. So `\verb` is not executed and so `{` is seen as a normal (catcode 1) brace and so the argument to `\exactly` is never closed.

Even if you used (say) `\verb|&|` rather than `\verb|{|` so the end of the argument was correctly found, `&` would already have been tokenized, so `\verb|&|` would produce a tabular special character `&` not a verbatim one.

Comment: Is there a way of temporarily suspending tokenization of everything other than the closing `}`?

Comment: @JPi No, TeX has no way of storing untokenized characters, they exist transiently in the input stream but can not be manipulated in anyway.  You can of course change the tokenization rules (which is what `verb` does) but that only works at the top level, commands like `\verb` never work in the argument of another command.  except for `{}` brace matching you can use the \scantokens etex primitive or variants in luatex to re-tokenize tokens after the initial parse

Comment: By the way "TeX has no way of storing untokenized characters" – this is technically true, but in practice changing them to a safe catcode then `scantokens` them later (as mentioned after) works most of the time (of course the `\verb|{|` case is impossible to fix) – see `cprotect` package for an example.